# Grey scale image to Monochromatic scale?

Tags: c++, image, colors, scale, grayscale

I'm a beginner programmer, I know *C* and some *C++*, but never programmed GUI's, only console applications

I was asked to make a program that receives an image in grey scale, and turns it into an image in monochromatic scale of a color I set.

I want to do that, its easy if I can transform the image to a bitmap because I could parametrice the color I want to set with a moving scroll over a regular color scale. And then just make some sums and multiplication to the numbers on the bits, and that would get it to the color I want.

The problem is, I don't know how to do that, and I don't want to mess with complex libraries to achieve this. And I want to make it as simple as I can.

So, there's any library where I can support to do this? Or, how can I get this done? What should I study, or read to get this working? I don't want you making the program for me.

Comment: What is your input, an actual image file or a image buffer?

Comment: There is the standard book by Foley, van Damme, et.al which explains nearly all the necessary maths.
Inside boost is an image library which seems to be quite powerful, even I have not used it.
A great fast library is Intel's IPP.

Comment: I was looking for the library you recommended me Felix, but it seems too complex for the use I would give it. It seems I would waste a lot of time just getting used to the library

There is no way to get the image converted into bitmap, modify it and then save a new image from the bitmap? Because if that is possible, I just could get my programm running with just some iterations that would change the color of every pixel according to the intensity of grey it had, to the color I want

Comment: If you use a BMP file format you ought to be able to do this quite simple. The format is uncompressed and should be pretty simple to handle without any library.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a simple uncompressed format like **BMP** you can find many examples of code on the net that can read and write these.

An example could be [libbmp](https://code.google.com/p/libbmp/)